# Why does EWS api ErrorNonPrimarySmtpAddress error?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I have several user accounts in Office 365 tenant. Two of them are almost identical (have similar settings but different contact info and name). 
I try to fetch information (such as all folders and items) in user's mailbox using [GetFolder operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getfolder-operation) from EWS API that contains next body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
    <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
      <t:ConnectingSID>
        <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>Name.Surname@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
      </t:ConnectingSID>
    </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetFolder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
         xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties> </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </FolderShape>
      <FolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="outbox"/>
      </FolderIds>
    </GetFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can successfully get info for one of these two mailboxes but when an error reply with the next body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorNonPrimarySmtpAddress</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The primary SMTP address must be specified when referencing a mailbox.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorNonPrimarySmtpAddress</e:ResponseCode>
        <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The primary SMTP address must be specified when referencing a mailbox.</e:Message>
        <t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
          <t:Value Name="Primary"/>
        </t:MessageXml>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Why do I get such ErrorNonPrimarySmtpAddress error response? What can be the problem when I fetch data in the mailbox of the second user?

Comment: What is the request that returns that error? *Are* you specifying the primary SMTP address rather one of the proxy SMTP addresses?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I've just updated the description and provided EWS GetFolder operation body that I use when I fetch info about folder in user mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the primary SMTP address - I doubt Name.Surname@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com is the primary address.

Open the address book in Outlook (Ctrl+Shift+B), open the user, switch to the "E-mail Addresses" tab, look for the address with the "SMTP:" prefix (note the caps).

Comment: you probably suggest using Outlook desktop client but I don't use it. How can I find this in Office 365 Online? And why Name.Surname@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com can't be a primary address?

Comment: It can be, but most likely it is not - no sane company would expose something like mycompany.onmicrosoft.com instead of mycompany.com to the outside world.

Comment: When you send an email from that account to an external address (e.,g. Yahoo or Gmail), what is the SMTP address associated with the sender? That woudl be the primary SMTP address.

Comment: Actually I only know the mail of every user in the same form: Name.Surname@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com  And I can see this in Office 365 "Microsoft 365 admin center" under the "Users" tab as well.

Comment: When you edit the user's email addresses, on top of the screen you will see the current default email address  - "Primary email address and username"

Comment: No user's email addresses have been changed. The default email address is used.

Comment: Are there any other proxy addresses for that user?

Comment: No aliases are set for users - just one email address that is visible in "primary email address" section in user info in "Microsoft 365 admin center".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183792/discussion-between-vasyl-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Comment: I cannot think of anything. You might be better off opening a support case with MS.